# how can I clear a bitmap memory in real time?

Tags: java, android, performance

I create 14 Bitmap objects like this:

```
bmp[0]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0000);
bmp[1]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0001);
bmp[2]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0002);
bmp[3]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0003);
bmp[4]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0004);
bmp[5]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0005);
bmp[6]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0006);
bmp[7]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0007);
bmp[8]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0008);
bmp[9]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0009);
bmp[10]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0010);
bmp[11]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0011);
bmp[12]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0012);
bmp[13]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a0013);
```

those Bitmaps are used to make an animation of the background, the resources are 14 jpj images of 320x480 pixels. so I created a custom view and then call the bitmaps at the onDraw method. Then I test the app on my phone that have the same resolution of my images, it run smoothly, then I try to use the app on a tablet with a larger resolution(like 1280x720), but my background don't fit the entire screen, so I investigate how fill the entire screen by make a new bitmap with different resolution based on the device resolution and the result was this:

```
newWidth= context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
newHeight= context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

int contador=0;

        do{
             bmp[contador]= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp[contador], newWidth,                   newHeight,true);
       contador++;
       }while(contador<13);
```

Then I simply put these line on my onDraw method.

```
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp[i], 0, 0, null);
    i++;
```

If I test the app on my phone it runs fine but when I test it on my tablet throws me the "bitmap size exceeds VM budget" error... So I investigate a little bit more and I had the following solution: Create the original 14 bmp Bitmap objects and make a second array of Bitmaps called bmp2 and then only assign the bitmap when I need it and then clear it like this on my onDraw method:

```
   bmp2[i]= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp[i], newWidth, newHeight,true);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2[i], 0, 0, null);
 bmp2[i].recycle();
 bmp2[i]=null;
```

It work on my tablet and my phone but with a really bad performance I assume is because I assign the image in real time (on the onDraw method) but if I use the recycle method and don't assign again the bmp2 there will be not a new bmp2...

So finally my real question is: How can I clear some memory after I show my image and then when I need it again I can use it. Thanks!

Comment: you can try this bitmap.recycle() but its the job of garbage collector to free memory. You can load bitmaps in OnResume() and unbind or recycle in onPause() to free memory. Remember to recycle bitmaps when not in use. You should also scale down bitmaps if its too large to reduce memory consumed

Comment: I always called `recycle()` method when `Activity` that contains `Bitmap` being destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other have mentioned how scaling up small bitmaps to fill a large screen will not give high-quality results. But anyway, to answer your specific question, this is how you can draw your low-res bitmaps scaled up to fill the screen without memory errors.

You need to use one of the alternative `Canvas.drawBitmap()` methods which can scale your bitmap to the correct size while drawing.

For example:

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

From [the Javadoc](http://goo.gl/KPneE):

> Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill
>   the destination rectangle.

Set the `dst` rectangle to be the screen size you calculated earlier.
Then, you do not need to create separate scaled bitmaps in memory, so your problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks you so much, i will try it! : ) . Pardon me  if you don't mind could you hive me your opinion or answer about the question I ask to Ishan Khanna and EvilDuck about "I created an activity with an xml file like this setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);"??? I really want to know the answer XD

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no safe way of doing a fullscreen animation using scaled bitmaps. 
Why?

Let's do some counting. Each your initial bitmap is 320x480, yes? That's 320*480*4*14=8601600, which is roughly 8Mb of memory. When you scale to 1280x720, you add up 1280*720*4*14=51609600 bytes, which is 49 megabytes. 49 + 8 = 57 megabytes. Given that the newest tablets have maximum of 64 megabytes allocated for your app VM, no surprise it won't fit. And even if it fits with your tablet, what would happen if a Nexus 10 owner would buy your app? N10 has 2560×1600 resolution (not to mention that scaled bitmap would look pathetic).

Allocating single bitmap for single frame will hardly let you have a smooth animation, I'm afraid. You could try keeping a window of 5 bitmaps at once and recycling others, but still I don't thik it would be enough. Besides that would consume ton of CPU work for constant bitmap scaling and will destroy your battery.

If you really want an animated background, you should probably look at either OpenGL, or [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

Comment: Thanks you so much! I now aware of the limitations of the app VM a yes its looks crappy XD I will check the OpenGl an texture view options but if you don't mind could you answer me the question I ask to Ishan Khanna about "I created an activity with an xml file like this setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);" I really want to know why if I don't use a custom view to my Activity and use a xml file instead the image re-size by itself, there is no way that my object that  extends View  act like the xml ?  sorry if I don't explain correctly.

Comment: You don't need to store scaled bitmaps in memory. The Canvas provides ways of scaling while it renders. See my answer.

Comment: If I understood your question there correctly, then the reason is that in first case you are using a background attribute. The way this attribute works in android is that it renders the image across the entire view (which is your activity screen content). If you have a custom view, it would draw itself the way you tell in your onDraw(). Btw, you can set background for a custom view and stretch it with "match_parent". Yes, you can use draw a bitmap scaled on a canvas as Graham said above, but for such big scale factor it would look awful.

Answer (score 0):

You should design new bitmaps for your Tablets and Other Higher Screens and put them in the xhdpi folder under the res directory. This is the most efficient option. Let The Android OS itself pull the best fitting Resource for you.

See this for more detailed help 
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

This is what the documentation says

> Although the system performs scaling and resizing to make your
>   application work on different screens, you should make the effort to
>   optimize your application for different screen sizes and densities. In
>   doing so, you maximize the user experience for all devices and your
>   users believe that your application was actually designed for their
>   devices—rather than simply stretched to fit the screen on their
>   devices.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have one more question.I created an activity with an xml file like this setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); for my main menu why the background image re-size by itself? if I only have 1 .jpg for the menu and the resolution is 320 x 480 like the other ones used in the game screen,when I created my custom view for the activity that handle the game the backgrounds images don't re-size like the main menu? this is why I create new Bitmaps objects depending of the resolution of the devise, if I create different images with different resolutions my app will pass my 10 Mb limit : (

Comment: @JuanVillalvazo Maybe you should learn how to compress the size of the images, check the Color range in Photoshop and reduce it if your image doesn't need too many colors. It'll only bring down the size by a small number but when you'll do it on all the images you'll see and exponential change.

Comment: thanks : ) I think it will help compress it a little, but I'm still have the doubt about why if I created the view for my activity with an xml file the background image re size by it self, do you know why?

Comment: what is the resolution of the Image and the Screen can you please tell ?

Comment: Yes : ) the resolution of the Image for my Main menu is 320x480 like the ones I use for the background animation of the game screen. The resolutions of my cell screen is the same 320x480 and the tablet's resolution is 1280X720

Comment: Android Does the scaling itself to fit the Content.

Comment: But why when I create my custom view for my game activity, android don't act like before and scale to fit the content? there is no way that my object that extends View act like the xml ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much you compress the JPEG, it won't change the amount of memory the *decoded* bitmap uses.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times the GC would do the job.

You should have different bitmap resolutions handled by Android by folder (xhdpi, hdpi, etc.).

You should also check [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) in order to have lower quality version Bitmaps generated by your `BitmapFactory` signatures.

**Edit**

You might also want to consider using [WeakReferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to your Bitmaps.